# Inserir evento onclick no input criado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos, dinâmico

Tenho uma tabela onde o usuario pode inserir uma linha na tabela e depois disso deleta-la, caso necessário. Para isso, quando ele adiciona uma row, na segunda célula eu insiro duas células. Uma contém o conteúdo e a outra um botão criado dinamicamente.
Meu problema está neste botão. Quando eu insiro 1 linha, ele deleta corretamente. Mas se eu insiro mais de 1 linha, ele sempre deleta a última que foi inserida. Parece que o evento onclick mantém sempre os parametros da última linha inserida. O código que cria este input e add o evento:

```
        function inclui_item_extra(itemExtra, origem){
            var tabela      = '';
            var prod        = '';
            var idInput     = '';
            var idItemExtra = 0;
            switch(origem){
                case 'p1'   :
                    tabela  = 'tab_item_extra1';
                    idInput = 'produto';
                    prod = document.getElementById(idInput).value;
                    break;
                case 'p2'   :
                    tabela = 'tab_item_extra2';
                    idInput = 'produto2';
                    prod = document.getElementById(idInput).value;
                    break;
                case 'p3'   :
                    tabela = 'tab_item_extra3';
                    idInput = 'produto3';
                    prod = document.getElementById(idInput).value;
                    break;
                case 'p4'   :
                    tabela = 'tab_item_extra4';
                    idInput = 'produto4';
                    prod = document.getElementById(idInput).value;
                    break;
                default     :
            }
            prod = prod.split("|");
            if(prod.length == 2){
                var itemExtra   = itemExtra.split("|");


                id = gera_id(itemExtra[0].replace(' ', ''));
                var table       = document.getElementById(tabela);
                var row         = table.insertRow(0);
                row.id          = id;
                var cell1       = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2       = row.insertCell(1);
                cell1.innerHTML = itemExtra[1];

                var deletaExtra = document.createElement("INPUT");
                deletaExtra.setAttribute("type", "button");
                deletaExtra.onclick = function (){
                    deletaItemExtra(id, tabela);
                }
            /*  
                deletaExtra.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    deletaItemExtra(id, tabela);
                });
            */
                deletaExtra.setAttribute("value", 'X');
                cell2.appendChild(deletaExtra);

            }else{
                document.getElementById(origem).value = '';
                document.getElementById(idInput).focus;
                alert("Produto não informado.");
            }
        }

        function deletaItemExtra(item, tabela){
            var x = document.getElementById(item);
            var id = x.id;
            //x.deleteRow(0);
            //x.parentElement.removeChild(x);
                var tab = document.getElementById(tabela);
                var linhas = tab.rows;
                var conta = 0;
                while(linhas[conta]){
                    if(id == linhas[conta].id){
                        alert(linhas[conta].id +" -- achei e vou deletar");
                        document.getElementById(tabela).deleteRow(conta);
                    }
                    conta++;
                }
        /*
                var z = document.getElementById(tabela).rows.length;
                var y = 0;
                for(y =z-1; y >= 0; y--){
                    alert('-'+ document.getElementBy.row(y).id);
                    if(item == x.row(y).id){
                        document.getElementById(tabela).deleteRow(y);
                    }

                }
        */
            if(document.getElementById(item) != null){
                alert('Ainda é encontrado no sistema'); 
            }else{
                alert('Foi totalmente deletado do sistema'); 
            }
        }
```

Eu tentei adicionar diretamente o evento no onclick e também com a função addEventeListener mas os dois tem o mesmo resultado.
Possuo uma função que não deixa existirem ids duplicados. Segue código:

```
function gera_id(ie) {
  var idExiste = false;
  var id = 0;
  while (idExiste == false) {
    id = "ie" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1) + '_' + ie;

    if (document.getElementById(id) == null) {
      idExiste = true;
    }
  }
  return id;
}
```

Comment: isso acontece porquê você está criando dinamicamente os botões mas usando o mesmos id para os mesmos, assim só irá funcionar o último id criado, você usa Jquery? Isso pode ser resolvido de uma forma muito simples com ele.

Comment: É interessante você adiciona-lo na pergunta. Lembre-se: Quanto mais detalhada for a pergunta mais rápido você obtém uma resposta.

Comment: Desculpe. Poderia me mostrar como fazer em jquery? ou alguma outra sugestão sobre qual o problema?

Comment: Matheus, onde é que você está chamando a função para randomizar o id? mostre também a função `deletaItemExtra(id, tabela);`

Comment: Adicionei as funções a pergunta.